# Break lines when importing a CSV into PHP

Tags: php, csv, import

I have been trying to import a CSV into the database, but I have stumbled upon a problem with probably my line-endings.

When I put the CSV file in an array, it takes the breaklines and creates new array keys for the sentence in a long text.

This is the output for what should be one array key.

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 16.39.01
        [1] => Jussen speelt Beethoven
        [2] => 
        [3] => Symfonisch
        [4] => Lucas Jussen - Beethoven
        [5] => Symfonie 1 & 2 en het Eerste pianoconcert
        [6] => "Pianotalent Lucas Jussen brengt met Het Gelders Orkest een sprankelend symfonisch programma. Onder begeleiding van vaste gastdirigent Christain Vásquez speelt de oudste van twee talentvolle broers Beethovens Symfonie nr. 1 en Symfonie nr. 2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] =>  afgewisseld met het Eerste pianoconcert van de beroemde dove componist.
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => Twee virtuozen op één avond: Lucas Jussen en Ludwig van Beethoven. De laatste gaf op 2 april 1800 in Wenen met een onorthodox beginakkoord voor het eerst zijn symfonisch visitekaartje af. ‘Ongepast voor een grootschalig concert in een ruim operatheater’
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] =>  schreven de recensenten de volgende dag. 
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => Zacht en kwetsbaar
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [0] => Pianotalent Lucas Jussen tapt uit een heel ander vaatje. Hij trad al eerder op met Het Gelders Orkest en wordt nationaal en internationaal geroemd om zijn zachte en kwetsbare manier van spelen. Na zijn studie bij Maria João Pires
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [0] =>  Jan Wijn en Ton Hartsuiker bekwaamt hij zich verder bij de legendarische Menahem Pressler in Amerika. Hij wint in 2011 de Concertgebouw Young Talent Award en twee jaar later de Publieksprijs van de Festspiele Mecklenburg-Vorpommern. 
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [0] => Bekroond met platina
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [0] => Samen met zijn jongere broer Arthur heeft hij een exclusief platencontract bij het roemruchte label Deutsche Grammophon. Hun eerste cd - met werken van Beethoven – is bekroond met platina. Vaste gastdirigent Christian Vásquez is dus in uitstekend gezelschap en opent het seizoen sprankelend met Beethovens Symfonie nr. 1 en 2
    )

[10] => Array
    (
        [0] =>  afgewisseld door zijn Eerste pianoconcert."
        [1] => Jussen • Beethoven • Concert Apeldoorn Arnhem Doetinchem Nijmegen
        [2] => Het Gelders Orkest met pianist Lucas Jussen en gastdirigent Christian Vásquez. Beethoven Symfonie nr. 1 en nr. 2
    )

[11] => Array
    (
        [0] =>  1ste pianoconcert. Apeldoorn
    )

[12] => Array
    (
        [0] =>  Arnhem
    )

[13] => Array
    (
        [0] =>  Doetinchem
    )

[14] => Array
    (
        [0] =>  Nijmegen.
        [1] => Christian Vásquez 
        [2] => Beethoven 
        [3] => Symfonie nr.1 in C
    )

[15] => Array
    (
        [0] =>  op. 21
        [1] => Beethoven
        [2] => Pianoconcert nr.1 in C
    )

[16] => Array
    (
        [0] =>  op. 15
        [1] => Beethoven
        [2] => Symfonie nr.2 in D
    )

[17] => Array
    (
        [0] =>  op. 36
        [1] => 
        [2] => 
        [3] => 
        [4] => 
        [5] => Lucas Jussen
    )

[18] => Array
    (
        [0] =>  piano
        [1] => 
        [2] => 
        [3] => 
        [4] => 
        [5] => jussenspeeltbeethoven_afbeelding
        [6] => jussenspeeltbeethoven_header
        [7] => 
        [8] => 
        [9] => 
    )
```

This is my code:

```
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', TRUE);
$file = fopen('import/import.csv', 'r+');

while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
    if (array(null) !== $line) { 
        foreach ($line as $key) {
            $line_array[] = explode(';', $key);
        }
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($line_array);
echo "</pre>";

fclose($file);
```

Anyone who has any idea?

Comment: It seems that your long texts are also having `;` and that's why explode breaks them too. try with something else.

Comment: what `echo $key;die;` shows? check and let us know

Comment: Too long to comment, but shows the same thing it would do in the array.

Comment: put that in your question. and sorry show us `echo "<pre/>";print_r($line);die;` put this line after `while`, check and show us

Comment: Thanks for helping, Anant. I fixed it by actually adding a separator and enclosure to fgetcsv.

Comment: glad to hear that. please put your answer here yourself and select it as an answer so that others can get help.thanks.